# Storing values from texbox into an array and then checking the length of input to match array size c#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am new to C#. I have been trying to take values entered into a text box, on a windows form, and then save them in an array.  I was trying to then get a message to be displayed if the input data was bigger than the size of the name.

e.g.  A person enters their name into a textbox. The array might have a size of `[20]`. So if the name is longer than 20 characters, a warning will be displayed.

I have this which works but is not using the array to check input.

```
       string[] name = new string[20];
       public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("empty");
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text.Length > 20)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Too many letters");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: ... and the question is?

Comment: How do you want it to use the array to check input? How are they connected?

Comment: You should tell the user what the maximum number of letters. Too many would be pretty frustrating.

Comment: You can also limit the number of characters allowed in the textbox to being with. `textBox1.MaxLength = 20` if you want to do it programatically and not by setting the property ni the designer. This way, you don't need to do any tests (other than for empty).

Answer (score 3):

You can validate the `TextBox` if has string or empty with [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) if you're using *Net 3.5 framework or later*

```
    char[] name;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int countChar = textBox1.Text.Trim().Count();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) //if (countChar == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("empty");
            return;
        }

        if (countChar > 20)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered " + countChar.ToString() + " letters, Too many letters");
            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
```

***EDIT:*** I realized that the OP want to store the `TextBox` values to array

```
        var toArray = textBox1.Text.Trim().ToArray();
        name = toArray.ToArray();
```

Comment: probably the OP wants `countChar >= [declaredArray].Length;`

Comment: Calling `ToArray` on an array?

Comment: the OP wants to store the `TextBox` values to `array` so i use the method `ToArray()` :)

Answer (score 0):

> but is not using the array to check input.

It is using `array` internally. `String` is `char[]` and `String.Length` is actually Length of Char array.

---

```
string[] name = new string[20];
```

You donot need `string[]` to store a `string` of length 20.

Answer (score 0):

For this task better use list:

```
List<String> list_string=new List<String>();
```

To add item You need:

```
list_string.Add("My String");
```

List is dynamic collection so you will never excced range.

Other way when you use String class.

**String** is char of array it is dynamic objec so You never excced range.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `name` array to `char[]` instead of `string[]`. What you're saying here is that you have an array of strings; like 20 full names instead of 20 characters of a name.

In your if statement you can use the array and the textbox for your conditions

```
else if (textBox1.Text.Length > name.Length)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Too many letters");
}
```

There are many other things wrong with this and could be done differently, but to focus on your question, I've left all other unrelated information out of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
    // Global string list
    List<string> inputList = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("empty");
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text.Length > 20)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Too many letters");
        }
        else
        {
            // Add to list if less than 20 but greater than 0
            inputList.Add(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, i realise this is probably the simplist question for everyone but I have been doing c# for only a few weeks!